# Is there any way to send an actual message via the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As far as I can tell, the Graph API doesn't provide support for creating new messages and replying to existing ones. It is my understanding that this feature has been disabled because of abuse. However, there are applications which definitely require such a feature and which are "good citizens". Is there any way that an application can be whitelisted to use such an API method?

Comment: See this thread, it has everything you're looking for:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken

Comment: Yes, but those aren't real Facebook messages at all. Since messaging is a core part of Facebook, I think this part should also be represented through the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think it's possible. Check the thread and message API's. It only seems to provide read access:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/